# Why does echo element in shortcode doesn't wrap in a div division

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I've this simple shortcode with echo output

```
function get_date() {

 echo date('l jS F Y');
}
add_shortcode('date','get_date');
```

Then when I go to the text widget area and place the shortcode [date] within the division, then it outputs the date but outside the wrapped division.

```
<div class="_date"> [date] </div>
```

It displays outside of div

Answer (score 2):

Then you have to echo your date insight your div. If you output it on top then it's displayed on top of your website.

```
<div class="_date"><?php echo date('l jS F Y'); ?></div>
```

I think in your case you should return the date instead of echo it.

Comment: you are right.. Just see them working. Is that the only reason?